# How to make my Navigation bar close when an item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, navbar

My navigation bar shows up on half of the screen when in mobile view, and i am trying to get it to close once an item has been clicked, instead of only being able to close it by clicking on the "X"

I am not that experienced with JavaScript, i am still learning, i've tried having a look at online tutorials but haven't been successful.

Here is the HTML For the Nav Bar:

```
<nav>
<div class="logo">
  <h4> Example</h4>
</div>
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#About">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
  if (link.style.animation) {
    link.style.animation = '';
  } else {
    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 
0.5}s`;
  }
 });
burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

});

}

navSlide();
```

I expect the Nav Bar to close once an item has been clicked, as well as being able to close by clicking on the "X"

Comment: Add a click listener to each navlink that calls `nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');`

Comment: Hi, @ChrisG can you explain this further please

Comment: Here's a fiddle where I added the listener: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wy9ajh0v/

Comment: @ChrisG , Thank you, i've now added the listener. But the "burger" does not toggle back when the nav bar closes, the "burger" is essentially 3 lines which when clicked, turns into an "X". so when i click on an item of the nav bar, for example "About Us" and the nav bar closes, the "X" is still present. I think this will require me to call the 'burger.classList.toggle('toggle'); ' function again but i'm not sure where to place it, could you help with this?

Comment: Right, I've updated the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks; Sorry to be a nuisance, but now when i click the burger to reopen after it has closed from clicking an item, the items do not show. Do i need to create another function for this? or re call a previous one? Hopefully this is the last of my questions.

Comment: I can't really help you there because it works for my fiddle and I'd have to see where your and my code differ.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is older but i found the solution .

Following the tips of Chris G in comments and adding some things more to solve the trouble about links do not get shown. That's how this code worked for me:

1. ADD the close nav in Js following Chris:

```js
const closeNav = () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  }
  navLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', closeNav));
}
```

That probably gonna make the nav bar close when you click on the links, but for me when i clicked again the links do not showed. so i copied the event who did the transition to the links and the code was like:

```js
    const closeNav = () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        
        //things i added to show the links again

        navLinks.forEach((link,index) => {
            if(link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            }else{
                    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });
      }
      
      navLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', closeNav));
    }
```

I'm a beginner with js, but hope it help everyone who got troubles with that.

Have a good one guys  :D